# How can I get programmatically get the version of a Moodle plugin?

Tags: moodle

How can I programmatically get the version of a Moodle plugin?

For example, if I know that `local_foo` is installed, how can I get its version number?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Moodle

```
$version = get_config('local_foo', 'version');
```

Or in SQL

```
SELECT value
FROM mdl_config_plugins
WHERE plugin = 'local_foo'
AND name = 'version'
```

Comment: And, to get the version of the Moodle core, call that same function with `'moodle'`, `'core'`, or empty string for the plugin name.  e.g.:  `$coreVersion = get_config( '', 'version' )`

Comment: Thanks, @Mike Finch.  I had forgotten that, and just now found this post again.  :)